# Is it necessary to url encode the file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, urlencode

In my asp.net mvc application I have the code:

```
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(attachment.FileName));
```

So that all the Chinese characters are url-encoded to something like `%5C%2D`. In IE/Chrome when users download the file, they get the Chinese file name(that is, IE/Chrome will automatically url-decode the file name). But in Firefox, they will get something like `%5C%2D%0A.docx`. Now I'm going to remove `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` in the code. But before doing this, I want to confirm that there is no security issues in this case. Would you please give me some ideas?

**EDIT** Corbin's answer is correct. But after removing the url-encoding of the filename, some users using old version IE will get strange messy file names. At last I do url-encode for those users only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

Unless I'm misunderstanding it, it looks like the name should just be in quotes, not url encoded.

Answer (score 3):

The name is allowed to be in quotes if it's ASCII.

If it's non-ASCII, then you have to use the encoding defined in RFC 2231 or the one in RFC 5987 or the one in RFC 2047... which browsers support which of these is a fun game, of course.  :(

If you just stick the raw non-ASCII bytes into the header, it will almost certainly look like garbage for a large fraction of users.

Comment: I was wondering about that since the headers would not be the correct character set. I was just hoping there was some kind of magic since the specs I found didn't specifically mention non ASCII chars. One of these days, I'll stop assuming. And hoping in magic :).

Answer (score 3):

please change your code as follow:

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser == "Chrome")
{
    filename = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(filename);
}
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

notes: your code miss "\"" for wrap file name in quotes